# Qt6: Implementing function, which accepts Qt slot with new syntax

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

Previous implementation defined signals and slots as `const char *`.

Now the implementation is much more sophisticated and uses templates. So my question is how to define function parameter as a slot in following example:

```
TargetlessTransition::TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::Id id, QState *sourceState, const char * slot) :
    QAbstractTransition(sourceState), id_(id)
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(triggered()),
          sourceState, slot, Qt::AutoConnection);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ook, if you need to pass a slot whch may have arguments.. you need also a signal  that matches same arguments. Assuming that you have those, the minimal what should be done is:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
TargetlessTransition::TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::Id id, 
                                           T *sourceState, 
                                           void (T::*slot)(Args...) ) :
    QAbstractTransition(sourceState), id_(id)
{
  connect(this, &TargetlessTransition::triggered,
          sourceState, slot, Qt::AutoConnection);
}
```

The obvious problem here: slot or signal should have same set of arguments. More clever way would be to constrain this that slot would have same argument list as `triggred`.

Another proplem: slot MAY be overloaded but it would be dealt on the caller side.

```
TargetlessTransition(id, substate, 
     static_cast<void(ProjectSubstate::*)(int)>(&ProjectSubstate::takesInt));
```

If `triggered()` is overloaded, you have to do something like that in connect:

```
connect(this, 
        static_cast<void(TargetlessTransition::*)(Args...)>
            (&TargetlessTransition::triggered),
        sourceState, slot, Qt::AutoConnection);
```

Various version of Qt have a variety of helpers to avoid typing that `static_cast`. For oddball implementation reasons, the syntax of those helpers is different from version to version of Qt, e.g. `qOverload::of` or `QOverload`. I ended up writing my own helpers.

```
/*  Simplest and not perfect portable helper
*   @code   
*        connect(sender, &QSender::sendSignal, receiver, 
*               slotOverload<void(int)>::of(&QReceiver::onSendSignal));
*   @endcode
*/
template<typename Func>
struct slotOverload {

    template <typename Class>
    static Func Class::* of(Func (Class::* v)) {
        return v;
    }
};

/// Creates `qSlot(int)(&QReceiver::onSendSignal)`
#define qSlot(...) slotOverload<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::of
```

PS. What if we need to figure out type of slot dynamically? I say, that's time for a stategy\command pattern when we would pass *something* that identifies which slot we use and the slot pointer reduced to `void*`... wait, doesn't that sound exactly like what Qt was doing with old syntax?

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
TargetlessTransition::TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::Id id,
                                           QState *sourceState,
                                           void (QState::*slot)() /*const*/) :
    QAbstractTransition(sourceState), id_(id)
{
  connect(this, &TargetlessTransition::triggered,
          sourceState, slot, Qt::AutoConnection);
}
```

Comment: Okay, what if my slot accepts an arguments

Comment: Change to `void (QState::*slot)(Arg)`? or use template instead. (does `"triggered()"` has arguments)?

Comment: yeah, seems this would require constructor to be a variadic template depending on arguments  of slot and type of target's class

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are riight regarding parameter - it must fit the triggered signal. However I have a problem with passing member function of QState derived class
`error: no matching function for call to ‘TargetlessTransition::TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::Id, ProjectSubstate*&, void (ProjectSubstate::*)())’
   99 |     new TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::SAVE_PROJECT_EVENT, projectsub, &ProjectSubstate::onSave);

note: candidate: ‘TargetlessTransition::TargetlessTransition(BaseEvent::Id, QState*, void (QState::*)())’
`

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor is `QState` a public base of `ProjectSubstate` and is that slot defined in `QState`? If latter not true, then it's template time

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie ProjectSubstate is derived from QState, that is right, however static_cast made work and it works :). Unfortunately the code become ugly.

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor You can make an object with static template function which would do that cast for you hiding behind short name. I'll look if I can find of my prototypes. Qt also got a helper .. look for `qOverload`

Comment: @Jarod42 Both of you helped me a lot. I gave tick to Swift because of assistance in further problems.